# Can I break an _each from inside another _each?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm new to underscore. For the outer _each-loop, I wish to count the conversions only once. In other words, I would like it to stop after the first conversion.y++. Is this possible?

```
_.each(conversions, function(conversion){
 _.each(user.apilog, function(event){
        if( conversion.conditional(event) ){
            conversion.y++;
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the underscore docs:

> It's also good to note that an each loop cannot be broken out of — to break, use _.find instead.

So no, it can't be broken from - their recommendation is to use `.find` - which breaks on the first `truthy` value you return from it - that won't help you in nested *each* though so you can either set a flag:

```
var flag = false;;
_.find(conversions, function(conversion){
 _.find(user.apilog, function(event){
        if( conversion.conditional(event) ){
            conversion.y++;
            return flag = true;
        }
    });
    return flag;
});
```

Or not use a nested `_.each` loop, one elegant approach would be to use a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript):

```
   var prod = cartProd(conversations, user.apilog);
   _.find(prod, function(item){
        return item[0].conditional(item[1]); // will break on find
   });
```

Although a plain old JS for loop would also work and would likely be faster.

Comment: Deleting my answer as this is more complete.

Comment: nice I was just looking at countBy but as far as I can tell it just put's one item in each group?

Comment: What is your loop actually trying to do?

Comment: the `user` has multiple `apilogs`, the idea is to test all `apilog` and if one or more of them is true, increase the value of conversion.y with one.